# Create data frame with one list column

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I have a list `abc = list(c(1,2), 3, c(4,5,6))`

I want to create a data frame `df` with 1 column `df$col1` which looks like the following:

```
[[1]]
[1] 1 2

[[2]]
[1] 3

[[3]]
[1] 4 5 6
```

How do I do this? Running `df = data.frame(abc = list(c(1,2), 3, c(4,5,6)))` gives the error

```
Error in (function (..., row.names = NULL, check.rows = FALSE, check.names = TRUE,  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 2, 1, 3
```

because data.frame() looks to convert this list into a >1 column data frame, spreading the each list element over different columns, and I can't find any argument in data.frame which stops it from doing so.

Comment: Wrap in `I`: `data.frame(abc = I(list(c(1,2), 3, c(4,5,6))))`

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a data frame and then add the list:

```
df <- data.frame(a=1:3)
df$abc <- abc
df
#   a     abc
# 1 1    1, 2
# 2 2       3
# 3 3 4, 5, 6
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you may need `tibble`

```
> tibble(abc)
# A tibble: 3 × 1
  abc
  <list>
1 <dbl [2]>
2 <dbl [1]>
3 <dbl [3]>
```

or `data.table`

```
> data.table(abc)
     abc
1:   1,2
2:     3
3: 4,5,6
```